# Update RSVG with SSH

Tags: svg, ssh, imagemagick, putty, rsvg

Is there any way to update the RSVG renderer from the Putty tool via SSH. It is now at RSVG 2.26.0.

[image]

I need this to convert an svg to png. The current version of RSVG does not produce a proper result.

Comment: If you are on a hosted server, you will have to ask your provider to do that for you. They will not give you access.

Comment: What OS is the remote machine running?